# How to use GitExtensions branch filter to show the local and remote of a specific branch

Tags: git-extensions

My question is all about the branch filter functionality of GitExtensions.

I have a branch called **branch123** and it exists both in my local (**branch123**) and in the remote (**origin/branch123**). My local is behind the remote by a few commits, and I have a new commit in my local. I have properly fetched and I can see all commits and branches when I am not filtering.

I am using GitExtensions (3.5.4.12724), and I want to filter the branches in a way that I see the local and the remote of a specific branch. I have enabled local and remote checks next to the branch filter:

[image]

And then I have tried to search for **branch123** or ***branch123*** but there is no way to see the origin of this branch, I only see the local.

Am I doing something wrong or what I am trying to achieve is not possible in GitExtensions?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I need it as well